# Signing Android App update

Tags: android, terminal, keystore

I am trying to update an Android app I put on Google Play after discovering that it doesn't work. The moment I changed the version number and name in the manifest, though, I discover that I cannot run the app on my phone to test it. It brings up a dialog box stating that "The apk for your currently selected variant is not signed."

I've been looking up keystore-related issues thinking that's the problem, but trying to tinker with that in the terminal in Android Studio has gone nowhere, since it treats it as it doesn't exist. I'm confused, what did I do wrong?

Edit: By dialog box, I mean it brings up the Edit Configuration box and has this message at the bottom:
"The apk for your currently selected variant is not signed. Please specify a signing configuration for this variant."

It says I'm selecting an unsigned release apk, even know I generated a proper signed one.

Comment: Changed the `name`? What name?

Comment: Do you have a multi-user device (Lollipop or later)? Make sure when you uninstall the debug app to test your release build, that you "uninstall for all users."

Comment: @zgc7009 there's an attribute in the Build Gradle called versionName, which for this one is "1.1"

Comment: @323go I connected my Galaxy S6 to my PC via USB in order to test. I forgot to uninstall it from my phone before testing the new version. I don't see an uninstall "for all users" for my phone, what does that mean?

Comment: Use `adb uninstall <packagename>` to clean off your device.

Comment: I used adb uninstall and it still doesn't work. When I click on the Build Variants window in the lower left-hand corner, toggling the Build Variant to debug will allow me to run it, but toggling to release will bring up the error. I generated a signed APK and made sure I had a valid (non-debug) keystore. Was there anything I missed?